# When does a fruit turn rotten?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

In "Animal Crossing New Leaf," my friend's "perfect fruit" turned out to be rotten. How do perfect fruit turn rotten?

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/120198/how-do-perfect-fruits-work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fruits in New Leaf **do not rot**. On a perfect fruit tree, **one of the last fruits** it produces before turning into a regular tree will be rotten. **Don't try to sell the rotten fruit**, everything else you sell at the same time will be rendered worthless and you will have to pay a disposal fee.

Turnips do rot every Monday, but they are the only items in New Leaf that rot with time.